# Equipment and parts monitoring system

Tags: database-design

I'm new in programming using Java and MySql and am currently developing an equipment and parts monitoring system.
What I want do is see all installed parts for specific equipment. For example the PC System Unit has HDD, RAM, DVDRW, Mobo, PSU, and CPU.  When I select that specific System Unit, the user should have the option to view the installed parts on it.

I have created equipment and part tables. A part is linked to equipment it belongs to.

I would like to ask for your opinions on whether I'm using a correct approach. All your comments are much appreciated. Below is the list of my tables and fields:

1. equipment

   - equipment ID
   - equipt_description
   - equipt_SN (If applicable)
   - equipt_Control No
   - equipt_deminsion
   - equipt_weight_kg
   - equipt_power requirement
   - equipt_model
   - equipt_unit
   - equipt_brand ID
   - equipt_category ID
   - equipt_isDeleted
   - equipt_status ID
   - warranty ID
   - equipt_remarks
   - group_ID
2. part

   - part ID
   - equipt_ID // ID of equipment in which the part belonged
   - part_description
   - part_SN (If applicable)
   - part_Control No.
   - part_deminsion
   - part_model
   - part_weight_kg
   - part_power requirement
   - part_unit
   - part_brand ID
   - part_category ID
   - part_equipment ID
   - part_isDeleted
   - part_status ID
   - warranty ID
   - part_remarks
3. department

   - department ID
   - dept_description
4. category

   - category ID
   - category_description
5. brand

   - brand ID
   - brand_descrition
   - category ID
6. transaction

   - transaction ID
   - ttype ID
   - equipment ID
   - part ID
   - department
   - account ID
   - transation_date
   - Transaction_Remarks
7. transaction_type

   - ttype ID
   - ttype_description
     Ex:

     - installation
     - pull-out
     - parts replacement
     - preventive maintenance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It will be nice if you look for the programming tutorial and try to do your own project. There are many examples out there online. There is no way I can help you create your whole project.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It looks like you've got a great start.  Now all you have to do is program it.  Best of luck to you!